# Returning a Crispy Form as response to ajax request

Tags: django, ajax, django-crispy-forms

i am trying to fill a form with data via ajax request. The is my attempt so far:

view.py:

```
def ajaxGetData(request):
    pnr=int(request.GET.get('pnr',None))
    instance=User.objects.get(pnr=pnr)
    form=User_Form(instance=instance,prefix="Userdata")
    return HttpResponse(form.as_p())
```

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '{%url 'ajaxGetData'%}',
      type: "get",
      data: {
        'pnr': pnr,
      },
      success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
          $('#Userdata-Content').html(data);
        }
      }
    });
```

It does work, but the form is not rendered with crispy-forms. Is there some code like

```
return HttpResponse(form.as_crispy())
```

That would return a crispy form?

PS:
I am quite new to Django and developing websites in general. I want to do a website where you can select a user from a list at the side of the page and then edit a whole bunch of data about him. From what i read doing a one-page-solution was the way to go for that. Would be quite thankful if someone can give me a hint if this is the right way to go about it.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Django Crispy Forms** has a helper [**`render_crispy_form`**](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#render-a-form-within-python-code) to render a form within **python** code.

So your views.py:

```
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from crispy_forms.utils import render_crispy_form

from django.http import JsonResponse


def ajaxGetData(request):
    pnr = int(request.GET.get('pnr'))
    instance = User.objects.get(pnr=pnr)
    form = User_Form(instance=instance, prefix="Userdata")
    ctx = {}
    ctx.update(csrf(request))
    #           ⬇️⬇️⬇️ 
    form_html = render_crispy_form(form, context=ctx)
    return JsonResponse({"form_html": form_html})
```

> Note that you have to provide `render_crispy_form` the necessary CSRF
> token, otherwise it will not work.

I suggest you to use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

jQuery would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'ajaxGetData' %}",
    type: "get",
    data: {
        'pnr': pnr,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#Userdata-Content').html(data['form_html']);
        }   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need install crispy module and later how use crispy forms in django https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html